# lsmeans() to infer if a mean is different from 0 after using mixed-model

Tags: mixed-model, lsmeans

my data:

```
values: 
[1]  0.69  0.99  0.49  1.10 -0.34  0.76  0.88  1.98 -0.14 -3.96 -2.73 -0.39  1.72
[14] -5.76 -3.69  0.13  0.42  0.27  1.10  0.87  0.84  0.54 -0.41 -0.36

groups:
[1] "2"  "2"  "2"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "4w" "4w" "4w" "5n" "5n" "5n" "5s" "5s" "5s"
[16] "7"  "7"  "7"  "8"  "8"  "8"  "9n" "9n" "9n"
```

I fitted a mixed model with the mean as predictor and got an output.

```
mod<- lmer(values~1 + (1|groups))

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.6092 -0.2184  0.2177  0.4001  2.0879 

Random effects:
 Groups                  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 DFClay_groups$B$D.a.akt (Intercept) 1.215    1.102   
 Residual                            2.536    1.592   
Number of obs: 24, groups:  DFClay_groups$B$D.a.akt, 8

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  -0.2083     0.5075  -0.411
```

The reason I chose this model (with ~1) is because I want to test if the mean of the data-set is the same as zero while accounting for the random effect governing the values.

To test for H0:  mean = 0 I used the lsmeans() function:

```
lsmeansmod<-lsmeans(mod, ~1) ### In the special case where the mean (or weighted mean) of all the predictions is desired, specify specs as ~ 1 or "1". (R-Handbook)
```

I wrapped the lsmeansmod into the summary() function.

```
summary(lsmeansmod, infer = c(TRUE,TRUE)) 

output: 
 1       lsmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 overall -0.208 0.507  7    -1.41    0.992 -0.411  0.6937
```

Is the p-value now telling me that the mean of the data that have been "corrected" for the random effect is not different from 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the relevant question is whether the hierarchical structure of the design/data is "meaningful" enough to be modeled. To test this, you need to first run an `lmer()` model with the grouping structure specified and then run an `lm()` model without the random effect(s). Once you have both of those, you need to estimate a likelihood ratio (LR) test comparing the two models using `exactLRT()` from `RLRsim()`. If the LR test is significant, that indicates that you need to account for the dependency in the data. It doesn't necessarily tell you *how* to account for such dependency. There are many different ways to do so (e.g., adjust standard errors, use dummy 'fixed effects' for the groups, or use a gee) and it is up to you to decide which is best for your application.